# Ansible: Using default variables for every task

Tags: variables, module, ansible

I'm sorry if this was discussed before or if there is documentation somewhere on this topic, but I wasn't able to find way to do this anywhere.

I'm having trouble finding out how to use host variables for every task in playbook, without having to specify them each time. I am working on some modules for configuring RouterOS devices trough API, using ansible local connection. Every time a task is executed, I need to provide it with IP address of device, username and password.

My hosts file looks like this:

```
[routers]  
mikrotik hostname=192.168.1.100 username=admin password=password123 dns_servers=192.168.1.1,8.8.8.8
[virtual]
virtual1 hostname=192.168.116.100 username=admin password=somepass dns_servers=192.168.116.1 gw_address=192.168.116.100/24
virtual2 hostname=192.168.116.110 username=admin password=somepass2 dns_servers=192.168.116.1 gw_address=192.168.116.110/24
```

My playbook then looks like this:

```
- name: Mikrotik TEST
  hosts: all
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    dhcp_pool: testpool
  tasks:
  - name: DNS Setup
    mt_dns: username={{username}} hostname={{hostname}} password={{password}} servers=192.168.1.1,8.8.8.8 remote_requests="true"
  - name: IP address setup
    mt_ip: username={{username}} hostname={{hostname}} password={{password}} address={{et2addr}} interface=ether2 disabled="false"
  - name: DHCP Pool Setup
    mt_ip_pool: username={{username}} hostname={{hostname}} password={{password}} pool_name={{dhcp_pool}} pool_range=192.168.116.10-192.168.116.20
  - name: DHCP Server Setup
    mt_dhcp_srv: username={{username}} hostname={{hostname}} password={{password}} name=TestServer address_pool={{dhcp_pool}} disabled="true" interface=ether1
  - name: DHCP Options Setup
    mt_dhcp_net: username={{username}} hostname={{hostname}} password={{password}} network_address=192.168.116.0/24 gateway=192.168.116.1 dns_server=192.168.116.1
  - name: Set static route
    mt_static_route: username={{username}} hostname={{hostname}} password={{password}} dst_address=192.168.10.0/24 gateway=192.168.10.1
  - name: Source NAT
    mt_nat: username={{username}} hostname={{hostname}} password={{password}} chain=dstnat action=dst-nat dst_port=8022 to_addresses=192.168.116.20 to_ports=22 protocol=tcp
```

As you can see, specifying hostname, username and password every time makes the playbook look overly complicated. Is there a way to predefine variables for every task? I'm ansible newbie and I do believe there's a way to do this, I just wasn't able to find it.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: How could Ansible possibly know why variables line up with the parameters? What would happen if you happened to have a variable named the same as some parameter on a module but you didn't intend to use that parameter at all? As such you must always specify every parameter you wish to use.

Comment: So there is no way to achieve this in ansible at all? I was trying to make a workaround on module level, by creating function that would go trough hosts file and used credentials from there. But I got stuck at the fact that the module couldn't tell for which host it was running. I suppose that one solution might be to use hostname as a parametr, making it one variable instead of three... Or maybe creating connection plugin, but I'm afraid that goes far from my programming skills.

Comment: You could write a role that does those configs with the default values and then only override what you want to override

Answer (score 0):

You should use global variables/ default variables for playbook
Also you should [use inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups) if you want define variables [in such manner](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variables-defined-in-inventory).

ansible-playbook -i /$HOME/inventory -l mikrotik ....

/$HOME/inventory:

```
[routers]  
mikrotik hostname=192.168.1.100 username=admin password=password123 dns_servers=192.168.1.1,8.8.8.8
[virtual]
virtual1 hostname=192.168.116.100 username=admin password=somepass dns_servers=192.168.116.1 gw_address=192.168.116.100/24
virtual2 hostname=192.168.116.110 username=admin password=somepass2 dns_servers=192.168.116.1 gw_address=192.168.116.110/24
```

Also you should [provide the variables through -e](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line) in file:

As of Ansible 1.3, extra vars can be loaded from a JSON file with the @ syntax:

```
--extra-vars "@some_file.json"
```

Also as of Ansible 1.3, extra vars can be formatted as YAML, either on the command line or in a file as above.